# Different length of footnoterule for \Xfootnote and \footnoteX series

Tags: footnotes, reledmac

Hello I'm trying to have different length of footnoterule  in reledmac, to distinguish visually from notes and different footnotes, but code does not have any effect. No difference i use '\Xbhookgroup' or '\bhookgroupX' or variants X on beginning.

Here is a code:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[noeledsec,series={A,B,C,D}]{reledmac}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{perpage}
\MakePerPage{footnoteA}
\renewcommand*{\thefootnoteA}{\alph{footnoteA})}
 \setmainfont[
    BoldFont={Dejavu Serif Bold},
    ItalicFont={DeJavu Serif Italic},
   % scaled={0.8},
    BoldItalicFont={DeJavu Serif BoldItalic},
    BoldFeatures={ Scale=1, AutoFakeBold=4.0},
    BoldItalicFeatures={ Scale=0.94},
    ItalicFeatures={ Scale=0.94},
  ]{Dejavu Serif}
  \fnpos{critical-familiar}
  \linenummargin{outer}
  \lineation{page}

   \newcommand{\nolemma}[2]{%
     \edtext{#1}{%
       \lemma{}\Dfootnote[nosep]{\hspace*{-10pt}#2}%
     }%
   }

\begin{document}
\Xlemmadisablefontselection{}
 \Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}
  \Xarrangement[B]{paragraph}
  \Xarrangement[C]{paragraph}
  \Xarrangement[D]{paragraph}
  \arrangementX[A]{paragraph}
  \arrangementX[D]{paragraph}
  \arrangementX[B]{paragraph}
  \arrangementX[C]{paragraph}
  \Xlemmafont{\bfseries}
  \Xendlemmafont{\bfseries}
%  \def\footwidthA{\kern-3pt \hrule width 1cm \kern 2.6pt}
        \newcommand\footwidthB{ %
               \kern-3pt \hrule width 2cm \kern 2.6pt
                }
                \newcommand\footwidthC{ %
                         \kern-3pt \hrule width 3cm \kern 2.6pt
                         }
                         \newcommand\footwidthD{ %
                                \kern-3pt \hrule width 4cm \kern 2.6pt
                                  }
                                  \newcommand\footwidthA{ %
                                         \kern-3pt \hrule width 5cm \kern 2.6pt
                                           }
                \def\Afootwidth{\kern-3pt \hrule width 5cm \kern 2.6pt}
                \def\Bfootwidth{\kern-3pt \hrule width 6cm \kern 2.6pt}
                \def\Cfootwidth{\kern-3pt \hrule width 7cm \kern 2.6pt}
                \def\Dfootwidth{\footwidthD}
           \Xbhooknote[B]{\let\normalfootnoterule=\footwidthB}
                 \Xbhooknote[A]{\let\normalfootnoterule=\footwidthA}
                  \Xbhooknote[C]{\let\normalfootnoterule=\footwidthC}
                \Xbhooknote[D]{\let\normalfootnoterule=\footwidthD}
                  \bhooknoteX[B]{\let\normalfootnoterule=\footwidthB}
                 \bhooknoteX[A]{\let\normalfootnoterule=\footwidthA}
                  \bhooknoteX[C]{\let\normalfootnoterule=\footwidthC}
                  \bhooknoteX[D]{\let\normalfootnoterule=\footwidthD}
 %      \makeatother  
\section{Test Section}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\lipsum[2]\nolemma{lorem}{Critical lorem with no lemma} 
\lipsum[2]\footnoteA{footnote A}
\lipsum[2]\footnoteB{footnote B}
\lipsum[2]\footnoteC{footnote C}
\lipsum[2]\footnoteD{footnote D}
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

Comment: \Xbhooknote -> hook for a particular note, not for a group of notes.

Comment: \Xbhookgroup -> called after the footnote rule have been printed -> can't influence your not

Comment: ok..i got it..but question remains :) ...I tryed different ways to reset length of rule.one of them 'worked' somehow , but on the top of page appeared one 'rule', just before section name...don't remember now...

Comment: reledmac manual.6.11.2: „While \Xtxtbeforenotes is for typesetting code before notes, \Xbhookgroup and
\bhookgroupX (respectively for critical and familiar) are for executing code before a
groups of notes, between the rules and the printing of the notes.“

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in my quick answer, you first test could not work:

- `\Xbhooknote` and `\bhooknoteX` are hooks to use at the begining of a notes, when it is added to the list of notes.
- `\Xbhookgroup` and `bhookgroupX` are called after the footnote rules have been printed.

And in any case `\normalfootnoterule` is not called directly: what is called is `\Afootnoterule`, `\Bfootnoterule`, `\footnoteruleA` etc. So what have to do is just to redefine these commands, like in this MWE

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[noeledsec,series={A,B,C,D}]{reledmac}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{perpage}
\usepackage{libertineotf}
\MakePerPage{footnoteA}
\renewcommand*{\thefootnoteA}{\alph{footnoteA})}

  \fnpos{critical-familiar}
  \linenummargin{outer}
  \lineation{page}

   \newcommand{\nolemma}[2]{%
     \edtext{#1}{%
       \lemma{}\Dfootnote[nosep]{#2}%
     }%
   }
\Xinplaceoflemmaseparator{0pt}
\Xlemmadisablefontselection{}
 \Xarrangement{paragraph}
  \arrangementX{paragraph}

  \Xlemmafont{\bfseries}
  \Xendlemmafont{\bfseries}

        \renewcommand\footnoteruleB{ %
          \kern-3pt \hrule width 2cm \kern 2.6pt
        }
        \renewcommand\footnoteruleC{ %
           \kern-3pt \hrule width 3cm \kern 2.6pt
        }
        \renewcommand\footnoteruleD{ %
             \kern-3pt \hrule width 4cm \kern 2.6pt
        }
        \renewcommand\footnoteruleA{ %
            \kern-3pt \hrule width 5cm \kern 2.6pt
        }
        \let\Afootnoterule\footnoteruleA
        \let\Bfootnoterule\footnoteruleB
        \let\Cfootnoterule\footnoteruleC
        \let\Dfootnoterule\footnoteruleD
\begin{document}


\section{Test Section}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\lipsum[2]\nolemma{lorem}{Critical lorem with no lemma} 
\lipsum[2]\footnoteA{footnote A}
\lipsum[2]\footnoteB{footnote B}
\lipsum[2]\footnoteC{footnote C}
\lipsum[2]\footnoteD{footnote D}
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

This is not documented in the main handbook, but it will do (one day!) https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues/483.

In this MWE I have also corrected some bad hacks:

- if you want to apply a command to all the series, don't call it for each series, but just call it with no optional argument (cf §6 of the handbook, on the begining)
- Use `\Xinplaceoflemmaseparator` in place of hacking with a negative hspace.